# ruby/ssh/sqlite3 shell escaping

Tags: ruby, ssh, sqlite, escaping

I need a line/block of ruby code that does the following:

- starts an ssh shell to a particular user/host: `dev@localhost`
- within that ssh shell start a sqlite3 session on a given file: `/home/dev/current/b/test.sqlite3`
- executes a given line of sql: `update customers set mode = "Y"`

I have all the elements together. I can start the ssh shell, I can get the shell to start sqlite3, and I can cause sqlite3 to execute a line of sql.

My problem is trying to escape all the different layers of quotes.

And before it gets suggested, the sqlite3 file lives on a different server, which I do not control. All I have is an ssh username/auth-key. So using ruby-sqlite3 isn't an option.

Peter.

Comment: I am not familiar with sqlite. If you tell me the sqlite3 command you are trying to run, I can tell you how to escape it in the ssh command.

Comment: @dave4420 The [sqlite3 tool](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) can be run as `sqlite3 /home/dev/current/b/test.sqlite3 "update customers set mode = 'Y';"` or `echo "update customers set mode = 'Y';" | sqlite3 /home/dev/current/b/test.sqlite3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell command you want to run on the remote server:

```
sqlite3 /home/dev/current/b/test.sqlite3 "update customers set mode = 'Y';"
```

Shell command you want to run locally in order to run the above command on the remote server:

```
ssh dev@localhost \
  "sqlite3 /home/dev/current/b/test.sqlite3 \"update customers set mode = 'Y';\""
```

Ruby command you want to run in order to run the above shell command:

```
system "ssh dev@localhost \\\n"\
       '  "sqlite3 /home/dev/current/b/test.sqlite3 '\
            '\\"update customers set mode = \'Y\';\\""'
```

(I've added gratuitous line breaks (and thus gratuitous escaping of line breaks) in an attempt to avoid horizontal scrolling in these code samples.)